# Need help to group Managers and Employees in order in Groovy

Tags: xml, sorting, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a requirement to sort the XML from top to down org chart. The XML contains all managers and direct reports mixed up.It has to be sorted in a way that all managers need to be above in the xml and followed by direct reports.The purpose is to load the manager record first before his reporte in a system else it fails. I am new to groovy and need some assistance. Please advice how can this be achieved in groovy or XSLT.

```
<EmpJob>
<EmpJob>
<userID>5</userID> 
<managerID>3</managerID>
</EmpJob>
<EmpJob>
<userID>3</userID>
<managerID>2</managerID>
</EmpJob>
<EmpJob>
 <userID>4</userID>
 <managerID>3</managerID>
 </EmpJob>
<EmpJob>
 <userID>2</userID>
 <managerID>1</managerID>
 </EmpJob>
<EmpJob>
 <userID>6</userID>
 <managerID>2</managerID>
 </EmpJob>
<EmpJob>
 <userID>1</userID>
 <managerID>No_MANAGER</managerID>
</EmpJob>
</EmpJob>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def data = '''
<EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>5</userID>
    <managerID>3</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>2</userID>
    <managerID>1</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>3</userID>
    <managerID>2</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>4</userID>
    <managerID>3</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>6</userID>
    <managerID>2</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>1</userID>
    <managerID>No_MANAGER</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
</EmpJob>
'''

def xml    = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)

def ids    = xml.EmpJob.collectEntries { n -> [n.userID.text(), n] }
def root   = xml.EmpJob.find { n -> !ids[n.managerID.text()] } 
def nodes  = xml.EmpJob.findAll { n -> n != root }

def tree   = buildTree([node: root], nodes)
def result = flattenTree(tree)

println(toXmlString(result))

def buildTree(tree, nodes) { 
  if (!nodes) return tree

  // split nodes into children of tree.node and non-children
  def (cs, ns) = nodes.split { n -> 
    n.managerID.text() == tree.node.userID.text()
  }

  tree.tap { 
    children = cs.collect { n -> buildTree([node: n], ns) }
  }
}

def flattenTree(tree) {
  ([tree.node] + tree.children.collect { flattenTree(it) }).flatten()
}

def toXmlString(nodes) {
  def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
  XmlUtil.serialize(builder.bind({ 'EmpJob' nodes }))
}
```

sorts the xml nodes per your requirements.

When run, this prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy

─➤ groovy solution.groovy                                                                                          1 ↵
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>1</userID>
    <managerID>No_MANAGER</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>2</userID>
    <managerID>1</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>3</userID>
    <managerID>2</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>5</userID>
    <managerID>3</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>4</userID>
    <managerID>3</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
  <EmpJob>
    <userID>6</userID>
    <managerID>2</managerID>
  </EmpJob>
</EmpJob>

─➤
```

The code works by building a tree structure representing the employee-manager relationship and then flattening the tree back to a list of nodes.

Comment: I believe `def sorted = xml.EmpJob.sort { it.managerID.text().with { it == 'No_MANAGER' ? 0 : it as Integer } }` works for sorting as well 

Comment: Ha, yeah even terser and no need for the inject. Nice!

Comment: hmm...I take it back...I think. Replacing the id `2` with `200` in the xml (both user id and the manager reference) breaks the direct sort version whereas the `inject` one stays true.

Comment: I tried the above logic..I have around 1500 employees in my XML with managers of upto 6 levels.Not all get sorted..Is there any way we can fix it.

Comment: If you can provide a link to a data file or a representative sample smaller one we can take a look.

Comment: Or an example of data that did not get sorted the right way

Comment: Answer totally rewritten to support deeply nested manager employee relationships. Please let me know if this solves the problem as required.